# почему не видно результат работы sh скрипта?

Tags: linux, terminal

запускаю файл ./updater.sh из ключем force и без него, процесс как бы зависает и просто ждет. (ждал около 30ти минут).
нет ни ответа на работу ни результата(просто мерцает курсор слева скраю)

условия:
1.OC linux
2.файлу updater даны права

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 igor igor 2970 Июн 15 11:20 updater.sh
```

3.в процессе прописан скрипт который собирает css файл и формирует единый.(ничего масштрабного)

вопрос: 
а)почему нет так долго результата?
б)как можно посмотреть он вообще работает или висит?

прилагаю исходник что внутри updater.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/packages/PackageLoader/include.php');

PackageLoader::Get()->setMode('debug');
PackageLoader::Get()->setMode('development');

require(dirname(__FILE__).'/packages/Engine/include.2.6.php');

Engine::Get()->enableErrorReporting();

print "\n";
print "Database updated.\n";

try {
    Engine::GetCache()->clearCache();

    print "Cache cleared.\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "Cache clear error!\n";
}

file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/rev.info', date('YmdHis'));

 //$minify = new ShopMinify('/_js/cache/', '/_css/cache/', true);
// $minify->process();

/*
```

это не полный

Comment: Добавь исходник, не понятно что там внутри

Comment: скрипт может выкачить несколько гигабайт данный, а канал слабенький. Мало чего.

Посмотреть можно, если запустить через strace/ltrace. Если скрипт подвисает - там скорее всего будет понятно почему.

Comment: Для уже запущенного скрипта, сначала посмотрите `top` или `ps -ef | grep updater`. После того, как выясните pid много чего можно вытащить из [/proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) .

Comment: попробую завтра на работе попробывать ваш способ

Comment: Странно, что у вас в updater.sh PHP-код, - это чтоб никто не догадался?) Вообще, полезно смотреть `strace -fT -p <PID>`. Если нет вызовов в strace, то либо перезапустить и смотреть, какой был последний вызов, либо пытаться смотреть `pstack`. У меня один раз было что-то похожее, тоже с минимайзером CSS'а - оказалось, что я неправильно запустил и наткнулся на баг, при котором минимайзер ожидал ввода с stdin. (Если так, то можно попробовать в консоли ввести CTRL+D.)

Answer (score 3):

чтобы узнать, чем именно в данный момент занимается *shell*-скрит, можно добавить в начало файла (но после строки с [*shebang*-ом](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) вида `#!/bin/sh`, если таковая присутствует), строку:

```
set -x
```

после запуска скрипта на экран будут выводиться выполняемые им команды.

Comment: завтра с утра протестирую ваш вариант, спасибо